# Enable code coverage in VS 2010 ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

This may seem a bit stupid, but I can't find the answer so:
My team just moved to VS2010 ultimate, and we'd like to enable code coverage. All the instructions I've found mention to open the `Local.testsettings` file and go to the "Execution Criteria" tab.
Well, I don't have this tab, and I do have VS2010 ultimate, which is supposed to support code coverage.

Help please :)

Noa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should be a Solution Items Folder in your Solution Exlorer. Double click the Local.testsettings file.

A new window should pop up. There is a list to choose from. Entries such as General, Roles, etc.

Select the entry "Data and Diagnostics". There you can enable code coverage.

Comment: I did it like you advise. But no code coverage exists anyway :(

Answer (score 12):

[image: Screenshot for the Test Settings Dialog]

Do not forget about Button **'Configure'** !!!

1. Select `Test/Edit Test settings/your active settings/`
2. Select Tab `Data & Diagnostics`,
3. Select the row `Code Coverage`
4. Check `Enabled`
5. Click the small **Configure** symbol on top of the grid.
6. Check all assemblies you want to collect code coverage info from...

Comment: I always forgert to click this and then wonder why my build is not generating code coverage results.  I think that the configure button is in a dubious place; it should be more prominent.

Comment: I am not sure, but something has changed in 2012 version :)

Comment: If you have a TFS 2010 and you are working in .NET4 projects using VS 2012 BEWARE -- Enabling code coverage via the VS2012 GUI adds refrences to Version=11.0.0.0 of the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CodeCoverage.CoveragePlugIn to your .testsettings file; it does the same for the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector.TestImpactDataCollector.  This means that unless your build server has VS2012 installed, the code coverage and test impact analysis will not work.  To remedy this, simply manually edit the .testsettings file and change the 11.0 to 10.

Answer (score 2):

Just to sum it up:

There should be `Solution Items` folder in your solution explorer, which should contain `Local.testsettings` file.
Double click it, go to `Data and Diagnostics` in opened window, enable `Code Coverage` there. Then click on `Configure` button there and check assemblys you wish Code Coverage to work for. `Apply` your settings, now Code Coverage should work.

In case you don't have `Solution Items` folder, or there is no `Local.testsettings` file, you might just create new `Test Project`. It will create `Local.testsettings`. You might remove new Test Project if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps for VS 2010 Ultimate

1. Double click Local.Testsettings
2. Click on Data and Diagnostics tab
3. Check code coverage
4. Double click on that code coverage row
5. Select dll that you need to check the code coverage for
6. Click Apply and Close

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a local.testsettings file you can cause a new one to be created.

Simply create a new Test project, then delete it -- you should then have a `Solution Items` project folder with `Local.testsettings` and `TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings` files, and a `vsmdi` file.